# Setup ssh & wifi on a headless Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: raspberry-pi

I've got RPI that I wanna ssh into for home projects. I don't own and do not intend to buy keyboard and monitor for it. I've played with it using raspbian, but wanted to try 64bit Ubuntu for few apps.

With raspbian all I had to do is touch ssh file and provide wpa_supplicant.conf with wifi networks. That doesn't seem to work with Ubuntu.

Also, how does file system work with RPI. When I mount SD card on macos, I can see only one volume. I remember I while ago I've tried to reverse engineer one application on RPI and there was a second linux volume that I was able to get into using some tools, but can't remember exactly what it was. Just trying to understand how volumes work in linux - I assume there's some separation between boot and os or something like that?

I apologise if this is too much of tangent from main question!

Comment: Yes, please only ask one question at a time. You can ask the one about filesystems separately, but make sure to include the output of some relevant commands such as `df` so we can understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help you with the first question unless you provide more info about what doesn't work and what you have tried. I will see what I can do if you describe your problem in a more detailed way.
Now to the second question: Installing a Linux distribution on a disk creates multiple partitions. Those are what you saw as multiple volumes. The reason for that is that different filesystems are good for different jobs and having some of your data separated from other data is a good idea in many cases.
Let me give you an example: You could for example create a home partition that contains all of the users data stored in /home/. That way you could easily reinstall your entire OS without touching any of your user data. Another example would be a swap partition that basically extends your RAM using your hard disk. This needs a special filesystem and a fixed size, which means that it needs to be a separate partition.
If you want to learn more about partitioning on Linux I recommend you [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning) in the legendary Arch wiki.